# mocking react class method with intl injected

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-intl

I have a react class with intl injected like below

```
import React from 'react';
import { injectIntl } from 'react-intl';

class CanvasView extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.create = this.create.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.create();
  }

  create(){
  // some code
  }

  render() {
    return //something;
  }
}

export default injectIntl(CanvasView);
```

While writing jest test I want to mock the **create** method.

I tried mocking like this:

```
CanvasView.prototype.create = jest.fn();
```

before shallow/mounting the CanvasView class. But, the create method is still being run. This is not mocking the create method since the class is wrapped inside injectIntl, I am not able to mock it.

Please help me to mock this.